# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http' in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services, wcf

We developed a .Net Core 3.1 application which consumes a WCF webservice (developed by us too). In our office all is ok.
We don´t use SSL in development but yes in production server.
In production when app tries to consume web service recieve the next error

[500].System.ArgumentException:
The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. (Parameter 'via') at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelFactory`1.ValidateScheme(Uri via) ....

¿How can I "transform" the http call to https?
We found information about .net 4.5 but not in .net core 3.1

PD: we can´t reach production wsdl from our office

Answer (score 8):

In your web.config file.
Change from

```
<security mode="None">
```

to

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

or set in code

```
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
...
binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
...
```

This change will allow you to use https instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

With SOAP 1.2, the answer is simply to switch from using `System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement` to `System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement`.